# How to search for icon (domMarker) at a specific location in HERE map?

Tags: javascript, here-api, heremaps

I want to find out if there is any domMarker at a specific location but I cant get it to work with the following method :

```
hMap.getObjectAt(55.685, 12.584, (obj) => { //obj is always undefined eventhough an icon exists within the given coordinates
    if (obj && obj instanceof H.map.DomMarker) { 
        console.log(obj.getGeometry());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Map.getObjectAt()](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.20.0/api_reference/H.Map.html#getObjectAt) expects screen coordinates, not geo coordinates.

add marker at map center:

```js
let domMarker = new H.map.DomMarker(map.getCenter());
map.addObject(domMarker);
```

get object at map center:

```js
let screenPoint = map.geoToScreen(map.getCenter());
map.getObjectAt(screenPoint.x, screenPoint.y, (obj) => { 
    if (obj && obj instanceof H.map.DomMarker) { 
        console.log('found a dom marker');
    }
});
```

Result:
`found a dom marker`